# Play event not firing on start on HTML5 widget

Tags: html, soundcloud

When SoundCloud HTML5 Player Widget is loaded with `autoplay` option, `play` event not firing when track starts.
However there is a timeout between loading the widget (or loading other URL into the widget) and when the track starts, so it's nice widget to call the event.

Is this by design or is it issue to be solved?

Comment: Your question is all but clear. What widget are you talking about? Could you provide a code sample to help us understand your problem?

Comment: there.
sorry, i tough it's clear by the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 Player widget should fire a SC.Widget.Events.PLAY event when the auto_play option is used. Here's a code snippet I used to verify:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Widget Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    iframe {
      display:block;
      border:0;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      height: 365px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="widget" width="100%"></iframe>
  </body>
  <script src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript (the contents of script.js):

```
(function() {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#widget');
    iframe.src = 'http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/43315398&auto_play=true';

    var widget = SC.Widget(iframe);

    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function(eventData) {
        alert('Playing...');
    });
}());
```

You can check out a working example [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XnSq/).

Comment: i've found the problem. in soundcloud widget playground, all events are binded on `iframe.onload`, even on `widget.ready` event.
thanks.