# Handling JS Events from SoundCloud Widgets

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, widget, soundcloud

I am a javascript novice trying to work with SoundCloud's new HTML5 widgets. I don't entirely understand events yet. The docs page just says

```
SC.Widget.Events.[something] — fired when [thing happens].
```

(via http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/html5-widget).

a code example would be great, and perhaps a basic explanation of how events work. right now i make elements interactive with

```
element.setAttribute("on[Something]", [function]());
```

which i understand is not the best way to do this and shows a lack of understanding of javascript events.
anyways, even a link in the right direction would be nice; i've been searching in vain for a clear explanation of event handling in javascript that goes beyond onclick etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the playground: http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288253/play-event-not-firing-on-start-on-html5-widget/10308295#10308295) is working example with `play` event.